# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 when testing my api get call

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

when i try testing my server side code which validate a user and logs him in,I get the above error.
i used jest for testing

Comment: May be port already in use. kill the port then try.

Comment: it did not work ,thanks for responding

Comment: Your server isn't running on 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I removed some tags from the title and added the 'supertest' tag. Can you try explaining a little bit more your problem, so that other users can understand it more easily? Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your remarks, i will do so